# 32809 Application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing an error only in few systems. error is " 32809 Application defined or object defined error"

my code is very simple

```
n_rows = worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

In MS Office 2010 Standalone machines code is working fine but in MS Offcie 2010 professional versions it is not working Properly.

Can any one help me on how to resolve the issue

Comment: Your code is really only a single line?

Comment: Maybe look at: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/260ebc8f-14d9-49d2-9742-a39351d4ce7e/excel-applicationdefined-or-objectdefined-error-32809?forum=exceldev

Comment: @TimWilliams not really but I am getting the error at that line.

Comment: This could be caused by an update for the Office application. Please take a look at this thread:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/473b1980-56b3-49ff-be71-3a60c0db048b/form-controls-stop-working-after-december-2014-updates?forum=excel  and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/260ebc8f-14d9-49d2-9742-a39351d4ce7e/excel-applicationdefined-or-objectdefined-error-32809?forum=exceldev

Comment: For fixes see http://excelmatters.com/2014/12/10/office-update-breaks-activex-controls/

Comment: I just Created the same file in the system where it is not working and copied the content....now the newly created file it is working fine.